# Modify Fill Factor of Primary Keys in all tables in MS SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, fillfactor

Is there any working method for modifying the Fill Factor arguments of all tables' Primary Keys in a Database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This script finds all the primary keys and for each one builds an ALTER INDEX statement and executes it.

```
---- change this to your desired value ----
DECLARE @NewFillFactor smallint = 92
-------------------------------------------
DECLARE @TableName varchar(300), @IndexName varchar(300), @sql varchar(max)

DECLARE inds CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY'

OPEN inds
FETCH NEXT FROM inds INTO @TableName, @IndexName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [dbo].[' + @TableName + '] REBUILD WITH ( FILLFACTOR = ' + cast(@NewFillFactor as varchar(3)) + ')'
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM inds INTO @TableName, @IndexName
END

CLOSE inds
DEALLOCATE inds

PRINT 'Done'
```